# ASP.NET (VB) app used to work, now gives “Overload resolution failed” on 2008 R2 IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net, vb

I'm migrating a legacy ASP.NET 2.0 (VB) application from an old Windows 2003 IIS 6 server to Windows 2008 R2 IIS 7.5. The application works fine on Win 2003, and 'mostly' works fine on the new server...

However, I'm receiving the strange error below when attempting to use the web app's file attachment feature, which I believe uses Telerik's RadUpload control.

Problem is, this particular app and file attachment feature (exact same .dlls) is verified to run on Win 2008 IIS 7.5, and I've double-checked the installation, all seems fine. Perhaps an issue with IIS settings or .NET/VB compilation?

Has anyone seen this, or anything similar?

```
Overload resolution failed because no Public 'Item' is most specific for these arguments:
  'Public Property Item(index As Integer) As System.Object':
    Not most specific.
  'Public Property Item(name As String) As System.Object':
    Not most specific. - /error.aspx <- http://appsrv001/error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/dialog/dlgAdvUpLoad.aspx

Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. (System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException)
-----------------------------------------
at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at ASP.error_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
-----------------------------------------
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Overload resolution failed because no Public 'Item' is most specific for these arguments:
  'Public Property Item(index As Integer) As System.Object':
    Not most specific.
  'Public Property Item(name As String) As System.Object':
    Not most specific.
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.OverloadResolution.ResolveOverloadedCall(String MethodName, List`1 Candidates, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, BindingFlags LookupFlags, Boolean ReportErrors, ResolutionFailure& Failure)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.OverloadResolution.ResolveOverloadedCall(String MethodName, MemberInfo[] Members, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, BindingFlags LookupFlags, Boolean ReportErrors, ResolutionFailure& Failure)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.ResolveCall(Container BaseReference, String MethodName, MemberInfo[] Members, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, BindingFlags LookupFlags, Boolean ReportErrors, ResolutionFailure& Failure)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
at APP.LegacyApp.Web._error.ImgExportPDF_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnClick(ImageClickEventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at ASP.error_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved by using Server Manager to remove the Web Server (IIS) Role and re-install. Perhaps was an issue with incorrect role service components.